# $stateParams for a state with only queryParameters in its url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have states that look like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('base', {
  url: '/base',
  redirectTo: 'base.all',
  template: '<div ui-view></div>'
})
.state('base.all', {
  parent: 'base',
  url: '?someQuery&another',
  params: {
    someQuery: null,
    another: null
  },
  views: {
    '': {
       template: '<div>base.all</div>',
       controller: function($stateParams){
         console.log($stateParams.someQuery);//undefined
         console.log($stateParams.another);//undefined
       }
     }
    //some views
  }
})
.state('base.all2', {
  parent: 'base',
  url: '/subPath?someQuery&another',
  params: {
    someQuery: null,
    another: null
  },
  views: {
    '': {
       template: '<div>base.all2</div>',
       controller: function($stateParams){
         console.log($stateParams.someQuery);//foo
         console.log($stateParams.another);//bar
       }
     }
    //some views
  }
});
```

I listen to the event $stateChangeStart and do `$state.go` when `redirectTo` is present.

My problem now is if I go to the url /base?someQuery=foo&another=bar

It will correctly go to the base.all-state but the `$stateParams` of the base.all-state will be empty. I don't want this state to have a subPath. The child state will only get the urlParameters set to $stateParams if it has its own subPath like `/base/subPath?someQuery=foo&another=bar` then it works fine and everything is set to $stateParams.

Is my attempt to have a subState with no subUrl, but only the queryParameters, possible? If so how?

Comment: maybe it's out of the scope of your question, why not to use basic params? in your `base.all` state you can set the following url: `/{someQuery}/{another}` and it should do the job

Comment: No, we want them as query parameter in order to keep the semantics of the url. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: as per [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#absolute-routes-) you can try to define an absolute route for the child state by prefixing it with a `^`. Thus your `base.all` state url would look like `^/base&someQuery&another`. I don't know whether this will work though, because the url is the same as that of the parent...

Comment: it sounded like a really good idea, but unfortunately it didn't work..

Comment: In your $stateChangeStart listener for the base state, you might check the toStateParams and fromStateParams and repopulate the toStateParams with the fromStateParams if they are being dropped.

Comment: @DanielNalbach it seems changing in the listener won't help. I wasn't  using the fromParams as the toParams but it is working fine in all other cases so it doesn't seem like this would be the issue. I tried to do that change and there was no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was as simple to not use the `redirectTo` and set parent state to `abstract`.

I think I was too blinded with the use of `redirectTo`.

And I'm not getting any warnings when routing `/base`, it seems it will automatically find the state `base.all` and everything works as expected.